# Keyboard hook with WinAPI C++

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard-hook

I am attempting to create a global keyboard hook that will be used to read keystrokes for a hotkey program I am creating and I've run into a few problems.  I need to show message box when user entred key word(for example "password"). How can I do it in this code?

```
#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

bool isCapsLockOn() {

   if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x00001) != 0) 
      return true;
   else
      return false; 
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;

if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {

    if (p->vkCode >= 0x30 && p->vkCode <= 0x39) // 0~9
    {
        switch (p->vkCode) {
            // 0 ~ 9 with Shift Options.
        case 0x30: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << ')';     else cout << '0';        break;
        case 0x31: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << '!';     else cout << '1';        break;
        case 0x32: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << '@';     else cout << '2';        break;
        case 0x33: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << '#';     else cout << '3';        break;
        case 0x34: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << '$';     else cout << '4';        break;
        case 0x35: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << '%';     else cout << '5';        break;
        case 0x36: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << '^';     else cout << '6';        break;
        case 0x37: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << '&';     else cout << '7';        break;
        case 0x38: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << '*';     else cout << '8';        break;
        case 0x39: if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) cout << '(';     else cout << '9';        break;
        }
    }

    else if (p->vkCode >= 0x41 && p->vkCode <= 0x5A) // a~z
    {

        if (!(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) ^ isCapsLockOn())) {
            cout << char(tolower(p->vkCode));

        }
        else

            cout << (char)p->vkCode;

    }

    else if (p->vkCode >= 0x70 && p->vkCode <= 0x7B) // F1 ~ F12.
    {
        cout << "[F" << p->vkCode - 111 << "]";
    }
    else if (p->vkCode >= 0x70 && p->vkCode <= 0x7B) // F1 ~ F12.
    {
        cout << "[F" << p->vkCode - 111 << "]";
    }

    else if (p->vkCode)

    {
        switch (p->vkCode)
        {
        case VK_CAPITAL:    cout << "<CAPLOCK>";        break;
        case VK_LCONTROL:   cout << "<LCTRL>";      break;
        case VK_RCONTROL:   cout << "<RCTRL>";      break;
        case VK_INSERT:     cout << "<INSERT>";     break;
        case VK_END:        cout << "<END>";            break;
        case VK_PRINT:      cout << "<PRINT>";      break;
        case VK_DELETE:     cout << "<DEL>";            break; 
        case VK_BACK:       cout << "<BK>";         break;
        case VK_LEFT:       cout << "<LEFT>";       break;
        case VK_RIGHT:      cout << "<RIGHT>";      break;
        case VK_UP:         cout << "<UP>";         break;
        case VK_DOWN:       cout << "<DOWN>";       break;
        case VK_SPACE:      cout << ' ';                break;
        case VK_ESCAPE:     cout << "<ESC>";            break;
        case VK_TAB:        cout << "<TAB>";            break;

        }
    }

}


return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

  int main()
{

HHOOK keyBoard = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, NULL);
MSG msg;
while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {    
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyBoard);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) ^ isCapsLockOn()))
```

In C++, `^` means bitwise XOR operation

You probably mean `||` for logical OR

To record the string, you can use `std::string` to declare a string. Add characters to it, then show it when user hit the Return key. You have to add handler for `VK_RETURN` as shown in example below.

If `#include "stdafx.h"` is not required then don't include it. `#include <stdio.h>` is C header for IO, it is not required here, you already have C++ header file `<iostream>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

...
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    static std::string str;
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) 
    {
        ...
        else if (p->vkCode >= 0x41 && p->vkCode <= 0x5A) // a~z
        {
            char c = char(p->vkCode);
            if (!(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) || isCapsLockOn()))
                c = (char)tolower(c);
            cout << c;
            str += c;
        }
        ...    
        else if (p->vkCode)
        {
            switch (p->vkCode)
            {
            ...
            case VK_UP:         cout << "<UP>";         break;
            case VK_DOWN:       cout << "<DOWN>";       break; 
            case VK_SPACE:      cout << ' ';            break;
            case VK_ESCAPE:     cout << "<ESC>";        break;
            case VK_TAB:        cout << "<TAB>";        break;
            case VK_RETURN:     
            {
                cout << "<RETURN>\n";
                if (str.length())
                {
                    std::string msg = str;
                    str = "";
                    ::MessageBoxA(0, msg.c_str(), 0, 0);
                }
                break;
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```